# SQL Update one table based on conditions in another table

Tags: sql, sql-update

Two tables.

```
Content (table),
   topic_id (primary key),
   data (text)

Topics (table),
   topic_id (primary key),
   content_type (text)
```

Both tables have the same primary key data (topic_id).

I need to update the data field (Content table) with the text "disabled" but only where the content_type field (Topics table) = the text "rvf"

I can: `SELECT * from topics WHERE content_type = "rvf";`

I can: `UPDATE content SET data = ("disabled");`

But how can I put those together.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Standard ANSI SQL solution (should work on any DBMS)

```
UPDATE content 
   SET data = 'disabled'
 WHERE topic_id IN (SELECT t.topic_id 
                    FROM topics t
                    WHERE t.content_type = 'rvf')
```

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly. This was in SQlite, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 13):

This should work if you are using SQL Server

```
UPDATE content 
SET data = 'disabled'
FROM content
INNER JOIN topics
on content.topic_id = topics.topic_id
WHERE content_type = 'rvf'
```

You can also update content with a value from topics by doing something like this:

```
UPDATE content 
SET content.data = topics.content_type
FROM content
INNER JOIN topics
on content.topic_id = topics.topic_id
WHERE content_type = 'rvf'
```

Not sure if it applies in this case, but it's good to know you can...

Comment: Isn't that missing the condition for `content_type = 'rvf'`

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE Customers
SET accountNo =(SELECT code
FROM Accounts_Index
WHERE aname = name)
WHERE name IN (SELECT aname
FROM Accounts_Index
WHERE aname = name)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).